# What is a reasonable number of goroutines I should use to operate on a huge payload size?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I want to implement partial response in my server to be able to do something like this:

[image]

So, I have a function that's called:

```golang
func DoPartial[T any](payload []T, fields string...) []map[string]any {
  // ...
}
```

This function takes the payload, that can have  million of records, and returns another payload only with the fields the programmer asked for.

I want to use concurrency to achieve this task. So I have a function that computes the number of gorutines I will use based on the payload size I get from my data source. Basically, I want to split the payload into ***N*** chunks, each chunk is given to a function that will be on a goruoutine. ***N*** is determined by `computeDelta(len(payload))`.

This is the function I'm using to compute the number of gorouties:

```golang
func computeDelta(payloadSize int) int {
  if payloadSize <= 1 {
    return 1
    }
  return int(math.Floor(math.Log(float64(payloadSize))) / 2)
}
```

And these are the number of goroutines I'd have to created based on the payload size.

```
size = 1               delta = 1
size = 10              delta = 1
size = 100             delta = 2
size = 1000            delta = 3
size = 10000           delta = 4
size = 100000          delta = 5
size = 1000000         delta = 6
size = 10000000        delta = 8
size = 100000000       delta = 9
size = 1000000000      delta = 10
size = 10000000000     delta = 11
```

I realized that sometimes the delta I use does not make any significant difference in the performance. Are these deltas reasonable according to the computer's architecture and payload size?. Is there a limit of goroutines that I should not pass?

Comment: In a compute-intensive workload, goroutines beyond the GOMAXPROCS number will not improve speedup. If your goroutines do not perform I/O, you can create that many goroutines regardless of the payload size. If those goroutines are performing I/O, in general you can go much higher. Hundreds of goroutines are common.

Comment: What's the job of the goroutine?

Comment: @EliDavis i just clarified my question